Anaconda python3.11 xlwings site package: Malware or not?
I was running my regular anti virus scanner using an Anti-virus software from Avast and the report flagged 3 potential threats. The thing is: they are all linked to a python3.11 site package called xlwings. I am curious to know whether I should worry about such a file:
/opt/anaconda3/pkgs/xlwings-0.32.1-py311hecd8cb5_0/lib/python3.11/site-packages/xlwings/addin/xlwings.xlam

Thanks.

Impossible to say - there is a legit package called xlwings, but if you have an uncorrupted version of that on your hard drive cannot be diagnosed in this form. Upload the file in question to virustotal.com, have it checked and decide yourself how much you trust it
